# If statement dilemma for text parsing

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

I'm parsing a large text file for correct TCP connections, and one of the things I need to do is check if the server and host IP addresses (There are 30 different hosts) have sent each other an SYN packet.

List of hosts:

```
HostList1 =   ['150.100.12.130','150.100.12.131','150.100.12.132','150.100.12.133','150.100.12.134','150.100.12.135','150.100.12.136','150.100.12.137','150.100.12.138','150.100.12.139']
```

Example lines from text(There are thousands of line):

```
2.000724 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto: TCP (6), length: 40, bad cksum 0 (->4280)!) 150.100.12.134.49153 > 150.100.0.2.57300: S, cksum 0x0000 (incorrect (-> 0xd6bb), 0:0(0) win 65535
2.000724 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 17, offset 0, flags [none], proto: TCP (6), length: 40, bad cksum 0 (->416f)!) 150.100.0.2.57300 > 150.100.12.134.49153: S, cksum 0x0000 (incorrect (-> 0xd6aa), 0:0(0) ack 1 win 65535
```

My current code, the server address is 150.100.0.2:

```
with open("serverLanTraceWithErrors.txt" , "r") as ParseFile1:
   for line in ParseFile1:
     if 'TCP' in line:               #Check if TCP proto is in the line
      Split1 = line.split(",")       #Split each line by a comma for future splits                                       
      Split2 = Split1[7].split(">")  #Split1[7] contains the two IP addresses, host and server and the direction of the packet
      Split3 = Split1[1].split(" ")  #Split3[3] will show the # hops 

      for item in HostList1:
          if 'S' in line:            #check if SYN flag is in the line

            if item in Split2[1] and '150.100.0.2' in Split2[2] and '63' in Split3[3]:
               print("SYN packet from host computer: %s to server completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3]))

            elif item in Split2[2] and  '150.100.0.2' in Split2[1] and '64' in Split3[3] and 'ack' in Split1[9]:
               print("SYN packet from server to host computer: %s completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3])) 

            elif: item hasn't been found sending or receving SYN flag...
               print("SYN pack from wherever to wherever not completed...")
```

Ideally there should be two situations where an SYN flag is found between the server and a host. host to server and server back to host. My problem is I can't find a way to make the last elif statement work, I need a way to say that if only one of the two top statements ever occurred which IP address it occurred with. Because for host 150.100.12.139, it only ever sends a packet to the host, the host never replies back with one and I the code to be able to point that out. My knowledge of python is very limited so ive been sitting here stumped for a while.

Comment: I would do this: assign two boolean vars (say a and b) to the value of the two if condition conditionals, and change the if to 'if a and b ... elif a ... elif b ...'. Then you know in the second and third branches that only one of the two events occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You said "*Ideally there should be two situations where an SYN flag is found between the server and a host*" so I'm guessing the last `elif` condition was to check if either of the above conditions worked or not. I suggest instead of the last `elif` statement trying using `else` as shown below.

```
for item in HostList1:
          if 'S' in line:            #check if SYN flag is in the line

            if item in Split2[1] and '150.100.0.2' in Split2[2] and '63' in Split3[3]:
               print("SYN packet from host computer: %s to server completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3]))

            elif item in Split2[2] and  '150.100.0.2' in Split2[1] and '64' in Split3[3] and 'ack' in Split1[9]:
               print("SYN packet from server to host computer: %s completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3])) 

            else:  ## item hasn't been found sending or receving SYN flag...
               print("SYN pack from wherever to wherever not completed...")
```

Let me know if it helped you.

EDIT 1:
After looking into comments I suggest you the following

```
            if item in Split2[1] and '150.100.0.2' in Split2[2] and '63' in Split3[3]:
               print("SYN packet from host computer: %s to server completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3]))

            elif item in Split2[2] and  '150.100.0.2' in Split2[1] and '64' in Split3[3] and 'ack' in Split1[9]:
               print("SYN packet from server to host computer: %s completed with right # of hops %s" %(item, Split3[3])) 

            elif item not in Split2[1] or item in Split2[2] :  ## item hasn't been found sending or receving SYN flag...
               print("SYN pack from wherever to wherever not completed...")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The issue if I write a statement like that is it prints that for every other situation where the other IP addresses aren't in the line either. So, one of those prints would be from the correct IP address, however, if none of the other IP addresses in HostList are in that line either it'll print it for them as well.

Comment: So tell me how you want the third condition to be as ? What exactly you want to check for ?

Comment: I guess what i want that last statement to check is if the IP address hasnt been found in either Split2[1] or Split2[2] with the 'S' flag in any line over the WHOLE file then print which IP address it is. Your previous suggestion is basically what I'm looking for, it's just that since I'm going line by line it prints for any of the other IP addresses that aren't in either Split2[1] or Split2[2] as well.